# What does it mean if passport returned but no refusal stamp or visa in it?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, russia, applications, pakistani-citizens

I’m a Travel Agent from Karachi, Pakistan. I applied for my client from Pakistan to the Russian Embassy in Islamabad. Completed all formalities: confirmed hotel, ticket, tourist voucher from Rusvisaonline, PCC etc.

The Embassy took the passport on 14th Nov and the ambassador even called the hotel to check that the reservation is confirmed or not. After confirming he kept just the passport, hotel and tourist voucher and visa form and remaining docs he returned.

After that, he said please pay the fees at the counter. After paying the embassy fees, he gave receiving date is 14 Dec, meaning exactly 30 days later. But when my client arrived today, 14th Dec, there’s no any refusal stamp on it nor visa was pasted. So what does it mean?

Comment: "Even ambassador also called to the Hotel".. lol

Comment: If the person you were in touch with actually claimed to be an ambassador (as opposed to a regular embassy employee), you may have been a victim of a fraud. I hope this is just poor wording of the question though.

Comment: Indeed: the ambassador is the person in charge of maintaining Russia's relations with the Pakistani government. That's a hugely important job and the ambassador is not going to be involved in visa applications at any level, and certainly not in secretarial work such as fact-checking applications.

Comment: If you really were told that the ambassador phoned the hotel, be sure that you were dealing with the actual embassy and not a fraudster.

Answer (score 5):

**It means somebody at the embassy messed up**.  Your client needs to go back to the embassy with their receipt and ask what's up.

Comment: The asker might have just used the wrong word but, if they were really told that the ambassador phoned to check a hotel booking, then it seems likely the embassy had nothing to do with it and the asker gave the passport to a fraudster.